# AJAX Login without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a login form and a AJAX Script to login without being redirected to the php script. It works great but there is just one small problem. When i submit the login form it prints out the output from php file (As expected) and it says that im online (As written in php script if the login details is correct). But i am not actually online until i refresh the page...

So my question is how can i use AJAX for a login form that prevents me from being redirected to php script but it logs me in to website without a page refresh.

So here is the AJAX Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.AJAXForm').submit(function (event) {
    var data = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: data.attr('method'),
      url: data.attr('action'),
      data: data.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        $('.output').html(data);
        $('.AJAXForm input:NOT([type=submit])').val('');
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

And here is my html form

```
<div class="output"></div>
<form action="functions/login.php" class="AJAXForm" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login-user">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input" name="user" id="login-user">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login-pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control input" name="pass" id="login-pass">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Create Account" name="submit">

</form>
```

And here is my php script

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include("../config/dbconf.php");

  function encryptsha($user, $pass) {
    $user = strtoupper($user);
    $pass = strtoupper($pass);
    return sha1($user.":".$pass);
  }

  $pass = encryptsha($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND sha_pass = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['user'], $pass);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
    echo "<div class='alert-success'><strong>Success!</strong> Welcome back ".$_POST['user']."</div>";
  }else{
    echo "<div class='alert-error'><strong>Error!</strong> Something went wrong, please try again.</div>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: *But i am not actually online until i refresh the page...*  Can you please elaborate on what this statement is referring to?

Comment: What criteria defines whether you are _"online"_ or not?...

Comment: For example if i write if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {echo $_SESSION['username'];} the username will not be displayed until i refresh the page

Comment: @TimLevinsson That's correct. When you originally loaded the page, you were not logged in. PHP runs on the server side so unless you re-load the page or echo this in your ajax statement, you will not see the name displayed...

Comment: You are required to load each element you wish to change dynamically with AJAX, your session variables will be accessible within those AJAX calls. By the nature of PHP you cannot 'logs me in to website without a page refresh' without the PHP code being parsed again

Comment: Alright, So this is not possible to do in any way?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You have to write a separate script to do the "logging in" and return to your ajax a variable telling you the session. What you are doing above is NOT using AJAX.

Comment: Okey. Thank you very much guys for all help and suggestions ! I will see what i can do

Comment: Also need to prevent the default browser submit process

Comment: FYI neither sha1 or **any** of the SHA family of hashing functions is suitable for password storage. You need a hashing function specifically meant for passwords, like bcrypt.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? @TimLevinsson

Comment: No sadly i have not been able to solve the problem yet...

Comment: I think i will need some example code to fully understand the comments here